# S3 Policy Allow Domains and Ip Address With OR Condition

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a policy

```
 {
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
     "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "IPALLOW",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "https://domain/*",
                    "http://domain/*",
                    "http://domain/*"
                ]
            },
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "ip/32",
                    "ip/32",
                    "ip/32",
                    "ip/32"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

it's just allowing domains to access objects
seems like I require or condition but cannot find it anywhere how

Answer (score 0):

Creating two objects to allow and Deny worked.

```
 {
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "IPALLOW",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "https://domain/*",
                    "http://domain/*",
                    "http://domain/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "IPALLOW",
        "Effect": "DENY",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ip/*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "ip/32",
                    "ip/32",
                    "ip/32",
                    "ip/32"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}